# How to find second highest number in ArrayList of Objects value

Tags: java, arraylist

This is what I got for the highest value, that seems to be working but im struggling to get the second highest value in a similair way.

```
public Show GetHighestScore() {      
    Show highest = shows.get(0);
    for (Show show : shows) {
        if (show.getScore() > highest.getScore()) {
            highest = show;
        }
    }
    return highest;
}
```

Comment: Could you please put the code of Show class so we can propose better solution

Comment: If your java version is 8 or higher, you can use stream to sort the ArrayList after that you can get the Kth smallest element in your case second smallest element :

    public Show kthSmallestUsingStream(List<Show> shows, int k) {
     if (shows.size() < k || k <= 0) {
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(k);
     }
     List<Show> sortedShows = shows.stream()
       .parallel()
       .sorted((sh01, sh02) -> sh01.getScore() - sh02.getScore())
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
     return sortedShows.get(k - 1);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public float secondHighest(ArrayList<Float> array){
  float highest = 0;
  for(float i : array){
      if(i > highest) highest = i;
  }
  float secondHighest = 0;
  for(float i : array){
      if(i > secondHighest && i < highest) secondHighest = i;
  }
  return secondHighest;
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile with 2 compilation errors on assignments _possible lossy conversion from float to int_  Also it makes assumptions about the values in the input `array` and will provide incorrect result in edge cases when there are less than 2 elements.

Comment: Of course. This is just the most minimalistic principle. With just a little bit of Java knowledge anyone can extend the code to their needs. If you don't know how to adapt the function to your code I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the typical problem of finding the K'th smallest/largest element in an array. I suggest you visit this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array/).
But in your case, willing to get the second highest number, you can simply make two passes on the array with a similar idea to selection sort or the way Luis Ka has provided.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in one pass and return appropriate `null` if no second highest value is available in the data and making no assumptions about the values in the input data:

```java
static <T extends Comparable> T find2ndMax(List<T> data) {
    if (null == data || data.size() < 2) {
        return null;
    }
    T max1 = data.get(0).compareTo(data.get(1)) > 0 ? data.get(0) : data.get(1);
    T max2 = data.get(0).compareTo(data.get(1)) < 0 ? data.get(0) : data.get(1);
    
    for (int i = 2, n = data.size(); i < n; i++) {
        T x = data.get(i);
        if (x.compareTo(max1) > 0) {
            max2 = max1;
            max1 = x;
        } else if (x.compareTo(max2) > 0) {
            max2 = x;
        }
    }
    return max2;
}
```

Tests (comparing to the fixed method of the accepted answer):

```java
List<List<Float>> tests = Arrays.asList(
    null,
    Collections.emptyList(),
    Arrays.asList(-1f),
    Arrays.asList(-1f, -2f),
    Arrays.asList(-1f, 1f),
    Arrays.asList(-1f, -2f, 3f),
    Arrays.asList(-1f, 4f, -2f, 2f)
);
for (List<Float> t : tests) {
    System.out.print("2nd max in " + t + ": ");
    System.out.print("find2Max() = " + find2ndMax(t) + "; secondHighest() = " );
    try {
        System.out.print(secondHighest(t)); 
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.print("FAIL: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output

```
2nd max in null: find2Max() = null; secondHighest() = FAIL: null
2nd max in []: find2Max() = null; secondHighest() = 0.0
2nd max in [-1.0]: find2Max() = null; secondHighest() = 0.0
2nd max in [-1.0, -2.0]: find2Max() = -2.0; secondHighest() = 0.0
2nd max in [-1.0, 1.0]: find2Max() = -1.0; secondHighest() = 0.0
2nd max in [-1.0, -2.0, 3.0]: find2Max() = -1.0; secondHighest() = 0.0
2nd max in [-1.0, 4.0, -2.0, 2.0]: find2Max() = 2.0; secondHighest() = 2.0
```